# How to delete muilt row data of excel file using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have 288441 record data in excel file. So now, i want delete all rows of file, before i deleted but it did very long time about 30 minus. My code below:

```
private static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, int rowColumn) {
    boolean flag = true;
    rowColumn = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    logger.error("Deleting row of 1_Portalraeume ....");
    while (flag) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(--rowColumn);
        if (row == null || row.getCell(0) == null) {
            System.out.println("Check");
            flag = false;
            break;
        } else {
            logger.error(rowColumn);
            sheet.removeRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

I need the help to delete it very faster. Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the rows from both the ends as follows,

```
int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();

for (int i=firstRow, j=lastRow; i<=lastRow/2; i++, j--) {
    sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));
    sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(j));
}
if(lastRow % 2 != 0) {
    sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));
}
```

This will reduce the time by half of the time what it is taking now.

Comment: Thanks you, but your code i found some problem, the first conditon if over the loop for and variable i is not undifine, the second record in excel file must be even, Otherwise, it will report a bug NullpointerException.

Comment: I just intended to help you with the idea. Not exactly with code snippet. This was just one of the ideas for your problem. But yeah, to correct the code you can declare variable before starting of the loop and assign "i" to it in the loop. Use the same variable in odd or even checking "if" block.